# Interpreting the results of randomized PCA in scikit-learn

Tags: feature-selection, scikit-learn, pca, randomized-algorithms

I'm using scikit-learn to do a genome-wide association study with a feature vector of about 100K SNPs. My goal is to tell the biologists which SNPs are "interesting".

[RandomizedPCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.RandomizedPCA.html) really improved my models, but I'm having trouble interpreting the results. Can scikit-learn tell me which features are used in each component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, through the `components_` property:

```
import numpy, seaborn, pandas, sklearn.decomposition
data = numpy.random.randn(1000, 3) @ numpy.random.randn(3,3)
seaborn.pairplot(pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['x', 'y', 'z']));
```

[image: Faceted scatter plot]

```
sklearn.decomposition.RandomizedPCA().fit(data).components_

> array([[ 0.43929754,  0.81097276,  0.38644644],
       [-0.54977152,  0.58291122, -0.59830243],
       [ 0.71047094, -0.05037554, -0.70192119]])

sklearn.decomposition.RandomizedPCA(2).fit(data).components_

> array([[ 0.43929754,  0.81097276,  0.38644644],
       [-0.54977152,  0.58291122, -0.59830243]])
```

We see that the truncated decomposition is simply the truncation of the full decomposition. Each row contains the coefficients of the corresponding principal component.

Comment: Many thanks!  And apologies for the delayed accept.